# PHPUnit not detecting missing argument

Tags: php, phpunit

I have the follwoing configuration:

1. PHP 5.3.8 from xampp 1.7.7
2. PHPUnit 3.7.13.

I am running my tests from both the commandline and from Netbeans on Windows XP.
Here is my code.

```php
class Wrapper
{
    public function wrap($text, $maxLength) {
        if(strlen($text) > $maxLength)
            return substr($text, 0, $maxLength) . "\n" . substr($text, $maxLength);
        return $text;
    }
}

class WrapperTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $wrapper;
    protected function setUp() {
        $this->wrapper = new Wrapper;
    }

    public function testWrap() {
        $text = '';
        $this->assertEquals($text, $this->wrapper->wrap($text));
    }
}
```

The problem is that the test passes although the function is obviously missing an argument. When using Ubuntu, the test fails as expected.

Comment: does the test fail is you throw an exception yourself? What is printed if you echo $this->wrapper->wrap($text)?

Comment: /**
    * @expectedException InvalidArgumentException
    */                                                                     public function testShouldWrapEmptyString() {
            $textToWrap = '';
            $this->assertEquals('', $this->wrapper->wrap($textToWrap));
    }                                                                       The echo test doesn't return anything.</br>An the test fails of course.

Comment: You should be getting a PHP error from the missing parameter, which will stop the test from executing, and not having it actually pass, but have the code stopped.  Can you post the output if you run this from the command line?

Comment: This is the output from the commandline:                          PHPUnit 3.7.13 by Sebastian Bergmann.
.
Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 3.50Mb
OK (1 test, 1 assertion)

Comment: Did you check your error reporting levels?

Answer (score 1):

This is a catchable type of error. In order to catch the error, you can create a custom error handler. See ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php ).

In order to catch this. You can try the following.

```
class Wrapper
{
    public function wrap($text, $maxLength) {
        if(strlen($text) > $maxLength)
            return substr($text, 0, $maxLength) . "\n" . substr($text, $maxLength);
        return $text;
    }
}

class WrapperTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $wrapper;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        set_error_handler(array($this, 'errorHandler'));
    }

    public function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
    {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
            sprintf(
                'Missing argument. %s %s %s %s',
                $errno,
                $errstr,
                $errfile,
                $errline
            )
        );
    }

    public function testShouldThrowExceptionWhenTheresNoParamPassed()
    {
        $this->setExpectedException('\InvalidArgumentException');
        new Wrapper;
    }
}
```